# want to filter username who can accept the DOT(.) , underscore(_) and Dash(-)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using the jQuery I want to filter that username which can accept 3 characters. With following validation

`.`, `_` and `-`

```
var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

So:

```
if (filter.test(currentval)) {
    //valid username
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to also include `. _ -` add them to your regex:

```
var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+$/;
```

Comment: i dont want to accpet the @ and  and it should accpet the -

Comment: That regex is not accepting the `@` but among others the `-` what is it that you are missing?